# Mysterious property taking effect in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging, firebug

I wouldn't ask stackoverflow unless this was a serious problem. I simply cannot figure out how to debug this particular problem. A left navigation unordered list element is being injected with an inline display attribute. I can't figure out what js code is doing this.

There is a file in **js/custom.js** that if I remove the file, the effect does not happen. So I assume its in there. I tried grepping for `.attr, .hide, .css etc etc` but nothing comes up that points to the **ul** element who's display effect I am trying to track down. I greped the php files for instances where it echo's or prints elements and nothing there either. I used firebug and firequery but nothing that is apparent comes up after inspecting the element. I tried breakpoints for attribute changes in chrome tools.

I suspect the answer would be in the DOM inspector but its mystified for me. I'm going to need to read up on the DOM tree views for firefox and chrome tools. But in the meantime can anyone give me a clue as to what is giving the **ul** elements with the **class subs**, in this [page](http://themes.kopyov.com/?theme=Crown%20-%20admin%20theme), their display property?

Comment: Sample code would help heaps!

Comment: I would suspect there's some minified code somewhere doing that. I've seen malware injected this way.

Comment: Well its not a smidget of code im trying to debug. If I know where the code is at I would have figured this out. A link to the page is given and thats where I am at. The element in question is also given. Its a ul with class 'subs'.

Comment: If you have bought that theme - the author would probably help you. Why haven't you asked him?

Comment: That would be something to consider. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: custom.js under crown/js folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Google Chrome Developer tools, to see if the CSS is what is hiding the element you are looking at?

Simply click on the element in the Chrome Browser, and select Inspect Element, then see what CSS properties are available.

Ultimately, what leaded me to this was, that I clicked on certain text, to open up the li's below. Then I search for the text, when I inspected the element, and found the anchor tag there with the text in it. I then assumed that the anchor had to be the culprit, and searched for its relate classname "exp", and found the js file that contained the function.

I looked at custom.js in crown/js folder, and found the following:

```
$('.exp').collapsible({
        defaultOpen: 'current',
        cookieName: 'navAct',
        cssOpen: 'active',
        cssClose: 'inactive',
        speed: 200
    });
```

The Li has an anchor element in it, with class of "exp"

```
<li class="forms"><a href="#" title="" class="exp"><span>Forms stuff</span><strong>4</strong></a>
            <ul class="sub" style="display: none; ">
                <li><a href="forms.html" title="">Form elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_validation.html" title="">Validation</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_editor.html" title="">WYSIWYG and file uploader</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="form_wizards.html" title="">Wizards</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

When clicked on this a tag, it gets another class called "active", and jQuery then injects the display code:

```
<li class="forms"><a href="#" title="" class="exp active"><span>Forms stuff</span><strong>4</strong></a>
            <ul class="sub" style="display: block; ">
                <li><a href="forms.html" title="">Form elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_validation.html" title="">Validation</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_editor.html" title="">WYSIWYG and file uploader</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="form_wizards.html" title="">Wizards</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

The CSS then handles the rest.

Comment: Well yes. I'm not a total noob lol. The css that is giving its property is not a css file. As I mentioned in my post, its an `inline` style being injected when the document loads.

Comment: The jQuery is injecting it - line 385 of custom.js

Comment: Sweet mother of god, that is it. Its amazing how you found it so fast.  I wonder why when removing custom.js collapsible breaks? Guess I need to read up on collapsible's docs. Thanks bunch.

Comment: You need to study more on jQuery too, but I guess you know everything about it already. Google chrome took me to the correct place immediately, when I clicked in the element, and saw the a tag with "exp", I could then search the js files for "exp"

Comment: Why would I assume that an anchor with class exp had anything to do with it? It was separate from the ul that had the property. And well, programming is a never ending learning process for all of us I'm sure. Again thanks.

Comment: Glad the Stack overflow community could help! :-) I assumed the anchor, because that is the text I clicked on!

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to figure out in Chrome.

1. Find the parent element that' holds the list.
2. Inspect said parent element.
3. Right click on the element and check "Break on subtree modifications"
4. Find out who added the element by inspecting the stack trace.
5. Profit!

Hope that helps you find the culprit.

Comment: I tried adding the breakpoint on its parent element and even all other parent elements but no call stack came up. It didn't break.